# как тогда работать с инструментами хрома если они врут

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive

```css
/* Start subscriber section*/
.arti-subscribe-section{
 position:relative;
 padding:50px 0px 100px;
 background-size:cover;
 background:#333333;
}

.arti-subscribe-container{
    padding: 0 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:start;
    align-items: center;
  
}



.arti-subscribe-title h4{
 position:relative;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:28px;
 font-weight:500;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content:center;
    align-self: center;
    
}

.arti-subscribe-title h4 span{
 color:#f74949;
 font-weight:500;
}


.arti-subscribe-text{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #ababab;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
}

.arti-subscribe-form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;

}



/*newsletter form*/

.arti-form-group{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
    margin-top:12px;
    
}


.arti-subscribe-form .arti-form-group input[type="email"]{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
    width: 35rem;
 line-height:22px;
 padding:6px 50px 6px 30px;
 height:45px;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-size:14px;
 border-radius:50px;
 background-color:transparent;
 border:1px solid #ababab;
 -webkit-transition:all 300ms ease;
 -ms-transition:all 300ms ease;
 -o-transition:all 300ms ease;
 -moz-transition:all 300ms ease;
    transition:all 300ms ease;
    
}

.arti-subscribe-form .arti-form-group input[type="email"]:focus{
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
    outline: none; 
    
}


.arti-subscribe-form button{
 position:absolute;
 right:0px;
 top:0px;
 width:140px;
 height:45px;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#ffffff;
 font-weight:700;
 background:#f74949;
 text-transform:uppercase;
    border-radius:0px 50px 50px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* End subscriber section*/


@media (min-width: 1366px) {
    

    .arti-subscribe-container{
        padding: 0 19.0rem;
                
    }
```

```html
<section class="arti-subscribe-section">
     <div class="arti-subscribe-container">
         <div class="arti-subscribe-title">
           <h4>До Миллиона просмотров объявления гарантировано <span> всего от 10 рублей</span></h4>
             </div>

                <div class="arti-subscribe-form">
                    <div class="arti-subscribe-text">Рекомендуем подписаться на наши новости. Мы не будем слать письма часто - некогда <span style="font-size: 2rem">&#9786;</span>, будем сообщать Вам о
                            новых услугах.
                    </div>
                                    
                    <form method="post" action="contact.html">
                        <div class="arti-form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" required>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-main-color">Подписка</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Столкнулся с таким промблемом, подгоняю паддинг блока под разные разрешения и столкнулся с тем, что хром -RESPOSIVE и выборе 1366px показывает одно - вроде все как надо http://joxi.ru/8AnQZJ3h78ZxK2, а при реальном разрешении(делаю полный экран 1366px вижу другое т.е имеется несоответствие http://joxi.ru/12MbXOVT07VGQA. Получается как тогда работать с инструментами хрома если они врут!? Заранее спасибо? Может что не так настроено у меня?

Метки

Comment: Не понял о чем речь - "скорее всего у вас неправильно заголовок прописан" о каком заголовке идет речь и что значит неправильно???

Comment: Код добавил посмотрите , плз

Comment: Можно увидеть код между `<head> </head>` ? Грешу на неправильно установленный мета тег, в частности вьюпорт.

Comment: <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">

Comment: Проверь размер шрифта, не меняется ли он для меньшего разрешения экрана?!

Comment: НЕТ НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ, в вопросе рассматривается ИМЕННО ОДНО И ТОЖЕ РАЗРЕШЕНИЕ